# Is it safe to change name to an already deployed Android app?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I have an app on the Google Play, already in production. I'm going to submit an update. The update includes a different name for my app (the APK still uses the same app ID of course).

Is it safe to do so? Do the clients will see the app with the different name or will they end up with two app icons on the home screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to change the app's display name (android:label in the manifest) to anything you want. The Android OS and Google Play Store will consider all APKs with the same package name (e.g. com.example.myapp) as referring to the same app. Any new version with a different display name will thus replace any previously installed version of the same app on the launcher.

If you want, you can have multiple launcher icons for the same app. Simply add

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

to every activity that you want to show up on the launcher.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to don't do so.
As you said that update will change the name of the app, this it's also harder to find by your older users and that's how your user lists may reduce.

Comment: ok but you didn't answer my question: will the clients see the same app with the different name or two apps in their home screens, one with the previous name and another one with the new name?

Comment: Nope older version will replace by newer version and that's how new name and icon will shown. Byt if the user installed both the older and newer version then both will show